# Why does Edo Tensei Madara have Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

1. Edo Tensei restores a person the way they were at the time of their death. When Madara died, he was wrinkly and old. How come Edo Tensei Madara is brand new?
2. Rinnegan is not a kekkei genkai/tota. Why does Edo Tensei Madara still possess the Rinnegan when, at the time of his death, he wasn't possessing Rinnegan (because he implanted them onto Nagato)?
3. Madara lost vision in one eye due to usage of Izanagi, but after awakening the Rinnegan, was he able to restore his Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan that he lost?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by EMS in this context?

Comment: @kuwaly Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the Edo Tensei doesn't just restores the body at the exactly time of death, but it does it as if it was brand new, the body is kind like 'reborn'. We see it on how:

- Edo Tensei Deidara had both eyes instead of his robot left eye;
- Edo Tensei Sasori had a 'human' body instead of a puppet one;
- Edo Tensei Nagato had his Rinnegans even tho Tobi had taken his eyes from his body;
- Edo Tensei itachi had his Sharingans even tho they were transplanted on Sasuke.

Now when it comes to Madara, Kabuto had aprimorated the Edo Tensei Jutso so when he brought Madara back to life he was younger and stronger than he was when he died.

Here's the image after he showed everyone that he has a pair of Rinnegan. Kabuto mentions that he made modifications to the body.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE. Could you provide the sources/references to this scene? You can always [edit] your post to improve the detail.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this definitely a plothole. Madara was having rinnegan in eyes when his very eyes (literally) were located elsewhere.

The question of getting back lost due from izanagi applies to both edo tensei eyes and actual ones.

My speculations to explain this (no proofs available):

1. Edo rinnegan got the eyes (EMS only) when Madara was at physical peak but his soul and memories experienced rinnegan before death and so activated it.
2. Izanagi loss - He stole an normal uchiha eyes and activated all of MS EMS and rinnegan having experienced it in other eye. All this near his death.

Comment: Not a plothole. Kabuto purposefully did this as his Edo Tensei version allows him to select different features from different times of an individual's life